# SQLite: How can I cast date time to yyyy-mm-dd format?

Tags: sqlite

I have data like this.

```
              Date 
2017-03-14-13:11:00.0000000-05:00 
2017-03-21-15:35:00.0000000-05:00 
2017-03-25-09:42:00.0000000-05:00 
2017-03-25-11:43:00.0000000-05:00 
2017-03-25-12:00:00.0000000-05:00
```

I need date looks like

```
   Date 
2017-03-14
2017-03-21
2017-03-25
2017-03-25
2017-03-25
```

I know many people asking similar questions but I couldn't find the code applies to the whole column.

Comment: Thanks for the great hint!! I treat it as a string and the code in below worked!

UPDATE table SET Date = SUBSTR(Date,0, 11)

Comment: If you have an answer, write it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

UPDATE table SET Date = SUBSTR(Date,0, 11)